# How do I use javascript code in a web request C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm not fully sure how to explain this: but I need to execute javascript code on a site via a C# webrequest, and use a GET request on the site with the js code executed.

I need to put the code

```
function getTitlesAndLinks() {
    var arr = [...document.getElementsByTagName('h3')];

    var filteredHeadings = [];
    var filteredLinks = [];

    arr.forEach(x => filteredHeadings.push(x.innerText));
    arr.forEach(x => filteredLinks.push(x.baseURI));

    var printToScreen = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < filteredHeadings.length; i++) {
      printToScreen +=
        "<div><p>" +
        filteredHeadings[i] +
        "</p><p><a href=" +
        filteredLinks[i] +
        ">" +
        filteredHeadings[i] +
        "</p></a></div><br>"
    }
    return printToScreen;
}
document.body.innerHTML = getTitlesAndLinks();
```

Into google's search and get the results

Any idea on how I can do this?

For more insight, I am using the Leaf.xNet library for my HTTP requests

I have tried to do this by adding java headers and stuff but I have no idea where to start

Comment: "I need to put the code ... into google's search and get the results" Can you elaborate on what that means?

Comment: So the equivalent of going to google.com and entering this code into the console

Comment: How does the c# play into this? Are you loading a page from a c# web server? That page would send back HTML, which can contain the JS code. Are you looking to inject this JS code in another site (not controlled by you)?

Comment: If I undersand it right you wan't to scrape the google search results and get them in your application running in C#? in this case my try directly to access it with the get result on `https://www.google.com/search?q=` + your search query and parse it as xml in your c# code. Otherwise you could use it in combination with a web scraping or browser lib. Not sure if Leaf.xNet includes something like that didn't used it before